# Control bones for bendy bones and attachment to mesh

Tags: bones

I'm new to Blender and using Blender 3.2.1. I would like to create mimic for a character using [`Bendy Bones`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/armatures/bones/properties/bendy_bones.html). In other words, I want to create bendy bones, create control bones for the bendy bones, connect them to a character mesh. I have encountered a few problems while trying to find a solution. Here's what I have tried:

1. I tried following this tutorial ([Blender #EasyRigging for Animators - Facial Rig (proof of concept) on Vimeo](https://vimeo.com/190801903?embedded=true&source=video_title&owner=944467)).
   I made the Bendy bones by importing a single bone. Then I changed settings to "Display as B-Bone" in *Object Data Proprieties* of armature in *Viewport Display*. And in *Bone Properties* I set 10 segments and size for the Bendy bone. [Auto Bone Controller](https://github.com/Bartemis/autobonecontroller) was required, but when I'm in *Edit Mode* and I add an sphere-empty, set shape for controllers to *Empty*, select the Bendy bone I’ve made and press *Add* in the addon, Blender reports an error. [image]
2. I have tried to do the same aforementioned steps in the finished file below the Vimeo tutorial, but it produced an different error. [image]
3. I tried to find the tutorial mentioned in the vimeo video in order to make control bones manually, but I couldn’t find it. If you have a link to it, please send it to me.
4. On this website I found a similar question ([Bendy bones problem - auto_bone_controller - Support / Animation and Rigging - Blender Artists Community](https://blenderartists.org/t/bendy-bones-problem-auto-bone-controller/688203)) but according to a small demo provided, it only makes bendy bones, but mot the control bones for them. It is not what I am looking for.
5. I tried bendy bones handles addon ([GitHub - gnastacast/bendy_bone_handles: Blender add on to add a new bendy bone object with handles.](https://github.com/gnastacast/bendy_bone_handles)), but just like in 3, it does not create control bones.
6. I tried to make a bendy bone following this video ([(19) Bendy Bones "Slug" Rig in Blender - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q6bdFPk6Y3E)). What was in this video 100% worked for me. But when I parent the bendy bone to the mesh twists terribly. [image]

It turns out that weight paint zone for the bendy bone is covering the whole mesh. I cleaned everything with removing weight paint from vertex groups and painted only eyebrow. But as I paint, the painted area gets twisted.

[image]

Links to the files
Weightpaint issue https://cloud.mail.ru/public/xDYi/Z2kjRhE8J
Auto bone controller issue https://cloud.mail.ru/public/Vosb/2aHhWwxpg

New links
[image]

[image]

Could you please tell me how can I make control bones for the Bendy bones and parent them to me mesh correctly? I would appreciate a link to a Nimble blog video on rigging with Bendy Bones too.

Comment: I can't open the cloud mail links you provided. you can upload blender files on https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: Thank you! I added new links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Suzanne rig has a few mistakes:

**1.** the *Armature* is scaled and rotated and these **transformations are not applied**. That results in strange bone deformations. Select the *Armature* and apply *Scale* and *Rotation* with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> in *Object* mode. This resets the values in the side panel to (0°, 0°, 0°), and (1.0, 1.0, 1.0), respectively.
[image: tranformation]

**2. you need to align the bones to the mesh in *Edit* mode properly**, not in *Pose* mode. In *Edit* mode, Blender automatically switches the *Armature* object to its *Rest Pose* and you can align the bones to the mesh. After you used *Parent To* you can switch to *Pose* mode, test the rig, and add Bone Constraints.
[image: screenshot 2]

Speaking of constraints: after you have done the layout of the bones in *Edit* mode, you need to reset the *Original Length* value of the *Stretch To* constraints in *Pose* mode. Just click the [X] in the input box to recalculate the value and the bone should be well placed.

*With Automatic Weights* for the bones of the eyebrows alone does not work very well, because Blender then extends the weights to the entire head and as a result, the mesh of the head, face, and ears moves with the eyebrow bones.

To prevent this, you have to paint the weights manually or add additional bones that limit the influence of the bones to certain areas. For the eyes, you need a ring and another ring for the eyelids. Rigify's face rig can give you an idea of where you have to place additional bones.

I have done this here exemplarily for the eyes. The bones "*Eyes Upper...*" prevent the deformation of the lower eye area. For the eyeballs, the rest of the lower face, and the upper and rear head I removed the weights manually.

[image: raise eyebrows animations]

About the issues with the *Auto Bone Controller* addon have a look at your other question → [Auto bone controller addon issue](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/273753/auto-bone-controller-addon-issue)

Comment: Thank you very much!