# Auto bone controller addon issue

Tags: add-on, bones

I'm new to Blender and using version 3.2.1. I don't know Python.
I have found an amazing video on Blender’s [`Bendy Bones`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/armatures/bones/properties/bendy_bones.html): [Blender #EasyRigging for Animators - Facial Rig (proof of concept)](https://vimeo.com/190801903).
But when I try to use the [Auto Bone Controller](https://github.com/Bartemis/autobonecontroller) addon, I set a tick on *use color for controllers*, add an empty-sphere, set *Shape* to *Empty* but then I get an error:

```
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
File «C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender
3.2\scripts\addons\autobonecontroller-master\autobone_op.py», line 270, in execute self.set_bone(context, ob, amt, main_bone, size_a, txt_a, size_b.
File «C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender
3.2\scripts\addons\autobonecontroller-master\autobone_op.py», line 214, in set_bone self.set_lock_and_deform(context, main_name, ob, txt_a, txt_b).
File «C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender
3.2\scripts\addons\autobonecontroller-master\autobone_op.py», line 152, in set_lock_and_deform ba.custom_shape_scale = scene.auto_bone_sacle_a
AttributeError: ‘Posebone’ object has no attribute ‘custom_shape_scale’
```

[image]

Comment: That's a third-party addon, not part of Blender so you really need to ask the author directly. However, it appears to have been last updated 3 years ago so almost certainly won't be compatible with recent Blender versions.

Comment: @JohnEason something really odd. why does the OP always use that link for auto bone controller which does not work https://github.com/Antonioya/blender/tree/master/auto_bone_controller. He also used it in his other thread https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/273703/control-bones-for-bendy-bones-and-attachment-to-mesh. So i keep editing the post to point to the only Auto Bone Controller addon i can find: https://github.com/Bartemis/autobonecontroller. EDIT: ahh maybe he forked the repository and made it private?

Comment: No idea! I've always found Github to be a maze of twisty passages! I only found the correct link via a search on Github itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a [breaking change in Blender 3.0](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/3.0/Python_API) and the addon has not been updated since then. The change was:

> Replaced `PoseBone.custom_shape_scale` scalar with a
> `PoseBone.custom_shape_scale_xyz` vector;

This breaks the addon in Blender 3+ but it's easy to fix. Change lines 152 and 156 in the file autobone_op.py to

```
        # 152: ba.custom_shape_scale = scene.auto_bone_scale_a -->
        ba.custom_shape_scale_xyz = (scene.auto_bone_scale_a, scene.auto_bone_scale_a, scene.auto_bone_scale_a)

    if scene.auto_bone_list_b != "*NONE":
        bb.custom_shape = bpy.data.objects[scene.auto_bone_list_b]
        # 156: bb.custom_shape_scale = scene.auto_bone_scale_b -->
        bb.custom_shape_scale_xyz = (scene.auto_bone_scale_b, scene.auto_bone_scale_b, scene.auto_bone_scale_b)
```

In Windows this file is located in C:\Users\*<user>*\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\*3.<version>*\scripts\addons\ after you installed the addon. Or change the file in the zip file and install the addon again.

Comment: awesome! thanks for sharing!

Comment: Thank you so much!